# Getting 0 values from mapping variable

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js

i added some data in smart contract mapping on remix i am getting values but with web3 i am getting 0 values

```
 const escrowCount = await neutralG.methods.totlaEscrows().call()

  for (var i = 1; i <= escrowCount; i++) {
  const escrow = await neutralG.methods.escrows(i).call()
  console.log(escrow)
  this.setState({escrows: [...this.state.escrows, escrow]})
}
```

this is my code

[image]

remix values

[image]

and this is web3 values where i am wrong?

Comment: Where's your contract's code? You're wrong in `for (var i = 1; i <= escrowCount; i++)` for sure. Should be `for (var i = 0; i < escrowCount; i++)`.

Comment: Are you sure the contract which you interacting from web3 has data in mapping or both contract is the same that one in the remix and the one you are interacting with web3?

Comment: i was wrong i have added mapping key with unique id and getting from count. now i have resolved it thankyou for your support